# My code is working on most but not all rows

Tags: vb.net

I have code that totals the values in cells in each row of a datagridview and puts the result in another cell in the same row. It's working on most rows, but randomly gives no result even though there are values in the cells. I can't figure out what's causing this.

```
 For i = 0 To ct
        tot1 = 0
        tot2 = 0
        tot3 = 0
        tot4 = 0
        tot5 = 0
        If Not IsDBNull(dgvPrice.Rows(i).Cells(10).Value) Then
            If dgvPrice.Rows(i).Cells(10).Value > 0 Then
                tot1 = dgvPrice.Rows(i).Cells(10).Value
            End If
        End If
        If Not IsDBNull(dgvPrice.Rows(i).Cells(11).Value) Then
            If dgvPrice.Rows(i).Cells(11).Value > 0 Then
                tot2 = dgvPrice.Rows(i).Cells(11).Value
            End If
        End If
        If Not IsDBNull(dgvPrice.Rows(i).Cells(12).Value) Then
            If dgvPrice.Rows(i).Cells(12).Value > 0 Then
                tot3 = dgvPrice.Rows(i).Cells(12).Value
            End If
        End If
        If Not IsDBNull(dgvPrice.Rows(i).Cells(13).Value) Then
            If dgvPrice.Rows(i).Cells(13).Value > 0 Then
                tot4 = dgvPrice.Rows(i).Cells(13).Value
            End If
        End If
        tot5 = tot1 + tot2 + tot3 + tot4
        If Not IsDBNull(dgvPrice.Rows(i).Cells(7).Value) Then
            If tot5 > 0 Then
                dgvPrice.Rows(i).Cells(21).Value = tot5
            ElseIf tot5 = 0 And dgvPrice.Rows(i).Cells(7).Value > 0 Then
                dgvPrice.Rows(i).Cells(21).Value = dgvPrice.Rows(i).Cells(7).Value
            ElseIf tot5 = 0 And dgvPrice.Rows(i).Cells(7).Value = 0 Then
                dgvPrice.Rows(i).Cells(7).Value = 0
            End If
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: Your last elseif isn't updating cell 21.  You don't need to check if `tot5 = 0` in those elseif branches since the first if is already checking > 0.  You could have one variable named total and just `total += ...value` since you only care about the totals.

Comment: Also, Cell(x).Value is an object.  You should be using Integer.TryParse to make sure you are getting a valid number.

Comment: Are you using the tot1 - tot4 somewhere else in your code?  Though, they could only be the last row's values.  If not you can simplify a ton of this code which may make it easier to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just adjust the column indexes to 10 To 13 and put the total in Cell(27). I added the inner loop to go through the columns. If the cell has nothing in it the `Continue For` just moves the execution back to the For line. The `dgvPrice.Rows.Count - 2` is because `AllowUserToAddRows` is True by default so there is an extra empty row in the grid.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim intValue As Integer
    For rowIndex = 0 To dgvPrice.Rows.Count - 2
        Dim total As Integer = 0
        For columnIndex = 0 To 2
            If IsNothing(dgvPrice.Rows(rowIndex).Cells(columnIndex).Value) Then
                Continue For
            End If
            Integer.TryParse(dgvPrice.Rows(rowIndex).Cells(columnIndex).Value.ToString, intValue)
            total += intValue
        Next
        dgvPrice.Rows(rowIndex).Cells(3).Value = total
    Next
End Sub
```